# Can't select query from second import

Tags: html

I define 2 imports.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Imports test</title>
    <link rel="import" href="./import1.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="./import2.html" />
    <script src="./scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        loadImport('import1');
        loadImport('import2');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**import1.html**

```html
<div class="import1">
    Import 1
</div>
```

**import2.html**

```html
<div class="import2">
    Import 2
</div>
```

**scripts.js**

```js
function loadImport(name) {
    var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
    var content = link.import;

    var el = content.querySelector('.' + name);

    document.body.appendChild(el.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Only first import works properly. Result of `content.querySelector()` is `null` for second. If I comment first import in `index.html` then second import works. What I do wrong? Chromium browser Version 75.0.3770.100.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector - `document.querySelector()` will only return the first matching item found - which is why your code works for the first match and not the second - it is only ever matching the first one.

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
```

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` and then iterate over them to access them (that means that you can actually have just the one call to the import function)

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="import"]');
```

or use an index to get just the import that you want - ie for the second import link

```
 var links = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="import"]');
 var link = links[1]
```